# Get directory files with PHP - Why would this not work on a standard php page?

Tags: php

I would like to populate a select input with files from a directory on the server. My code works as below in my drupal module, but it does not work in a standalone php file (meaning outside of the Drupal module and framework). This code is PHP - not specific to Drupal.

Yes, I do need it in the php file because I am calling it through jquery / Ajax because another select input is calling the subdirectory ($subdir) where the files are located.

I have even tried an absolute path (http://...), but it didn't help. It makes no sense to me that this works perfectly in my module, but when I pull up the .php file, there is no output.
**Edit:** There is output. I see the select box, but I do not see any options in it.

Does anyone have an idea of why this wouldn't be working? Here is my code:

```
$subdir = 'mysubdirectory';
$directory = 'sites/default/files/product_updates/' . $subdir;

$subdiroptions = '';

$files = glob($directory . '/*');

if(count($files > 0)) {
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $file = basename($file);
        $subdiroptions .= '<option value="' . $fiile . '">' . $file . '</option>';
    }
}

echo '<select>' . $subdiroptions . '</select>';
```

Comment: how about the absolute server path

Comment: Yes, I did try that, didn't help.

Comment: what does var_dump($files) say?

Comment: in that case there is no error with the glob function, there are simply no files to be returned... as per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php): *Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error.*

Comment: There are files. And if I put the exact same code into my module, it shows a select input with the files as options.

Answer (score 0):

You are scanning the directory tree from a relative point in your directory tree.

You can do a `echo dirname(__FILE__) . $directory` to see the path you are scanning.

I think you should try this:

```
$subdir = 'mysubdirectory';
$directory = '/sites/default/files/product_updates/' . $subdir;
```

And, a even better solution would be to compose a absolute path!

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I have tried an absolute path and it did not do any good. I am scanning the correct path, however.

Comment: You said: "absolute path (http://...)" but that is not the absolute path. The absolute part starts at / and not at http://